# Elastic Search fuzzy search not finding desired results

Tags: elasticsearch, fuzzy-search

In elastic search index i have trademark data.I have trademarks named `HILTON` in database, but when i search `hillytown`  its not finding `hilton`, but when searched `hilytown` it finds. How can i modify elsatic search to find `hilton` when i search `hillytown`

**note:** : `hillytown` has two `l`

The search that i tried is

```
$param = '
       {
        "query": {
        "fuzzy" : {
            "trademark" : {
                "value": "'.$keyword.'",
                "boost": 1.0,
                "fuzziness": "AUTO",
                "prefix_length": 0,
                "max_expansions": 100,
                "transpositions":true
            }
        }
      }
      }';
```

in

```
http://localhost:9200/watch_index_write/_search
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can get "hillytown" to match "hilton". [Elasticsearch allows](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/common-options.html#fuzziness) a maximum fuzziness ([levenshtein distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance)) of 2, but hillytown has a distance of 3 (need to remove 3 letters).

I haven't tried it myself, but the [phonetic analysis plugin](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/plugins/current/analysis-phonetic.html) might provide a way forward.

Comment: so there is no way through elastic search ?  here in this search http://www.wipo.int/branddb/en/#  
you can do that, i don't know what search they are using.

Comment: I haven't tried it myself, but the phonetic analysis plugin might provide a way forward: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/plugins/current/analysis-phonetic.html

Comment: I coudn't add the phonetic mapping to the existing index.. can you help me in adding the mapping for the field trademark in trademarks (type) in watch_index_write (index).

Comment: It worked by using the phonetic analysis plugin, Please can you add it your answer, so that i can accept your answer. And thank you so much for guiding me.